# How does the browser know a web page has changed?

Tags: browser, caching

This is a dangerously easy thing I feel I should know more about - but I don't, and can't find much around.

The question is: **How exactly does a browser know a web page has changed?**

Intuitively I would say that F5 refreshes the cache for a given page, and that cache is used for history navigation only and has an expiration date - which leads me to think the browser never knows if a web page has changed, and it just reloads the page if the cache is gone --- but I am sure this is not always the case.

Any pointers appreciated!

Comment: Ohh, your asking how does a browser know if a web page has been updated so it doesn't display the old one.   Well My guess is that it gets the HTML fresh on each load, but if an image or something changes it won't know until the cache is forcefully refreshed or deleted.  (just a guess)

Comment: just be aware that not all sites respect the 'Last-Modified' and/or 'Etag' HTTP headers... and until very recently, Stackoverflow.com didn't either!

Comment: How can a site choose to respect the Last-Modified header? Isn't it the browser's choice? Maybe stack overflow just doesn't set the head or its cache control header is overriding the last modified header...

Comment: ... if the Web Site **doesn't** provide a "Last-Modified"/"Etag" header.

Comment: Much different than not respecting the header...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Browsers will usually get this information through HTTP headers sent with the page.

For example, the Last-Modified header tells the browser how old the page is. A browser can send a simple HEAD request to the page to get the last-modified value. If it's newer than what the browser has in cache, then the browser can reload it.

There are a bunch of other headers related to caching as well (like Cache-Control). Check out: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Comment: +1 More detail than my reply, same idea though... good answer

Comment: A thing to note, modern browsers almost never send a head request on their own. While debugging app and accessing it through browsers, i have never seen a head request - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33444413/do-any-modern-browsers-ever-issue-an-http-head-request

Answer (score 9):

Don't guess; [read the docs](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt). Here's a [friendly, but authoritative introduction to the subject](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/).

Comment: I have to say I am bit lost in that rfc doc

Comment: That's why I provided the second link.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the Caching tutorial  Regarding the link to the Hypertext Transfer Protocol document, it would be better if you told us which parts of it were relevant to the question at hand rather than directing us to read the entire document 

Answer (score 3):

Web browsers send HTTP requests, and receive HTTP responses.  They then displays the contents of the HTTP responses.  Typically the HTTP responses will contain HTML.  And many HTML elements may need new requests to receive the various parts of the page.  For example each image is typically another HTTP request.

There are HTTP headers that indicate if a page is new or not.  For example the last modified date.    Web browsers typically use a conditional `GET` (conditional header field) or a `HEAD` request to detect the changes.  A `HEAD` request receives only the headers and not the actual resource that is requested.

A conditional `GET` HTTP request will return a status of `304 Not Modified` if there are no changes.

The page can then later change based on:

- User input

  - After user input, changes can happen based on javascript code running without a postback
  - After user input, a new request to the server and get a whole new (possibly the same) page.
- Javascript code can run once a page is already loaded and change things at any time.  For example you may have a timer that changes something on the page.
- Some pages also contain HTML tags that will scroll or blink or have other behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting along the right track, and as Jonathan mentioned, nothing is better than reading the docs. However, if you only want a bit more information:

There are HTTP response headers that let the server set the cacheability of a page, which falls into your expiration date system. However, one other important construct is the HTTP HEAD request, which essentially retrieves the MIME Type and Content-Length (if available) for a given page. Browsers can use the HEAD request to validate what is in their caches...

There is definitely more info on the subject though, so I would suggest reading the docs...