# Do any modern browsers ever issue an HTTP HEAD request?

Tags: http

I understand what a HEAD request is, and what it could be used for. Will any standard, modern browser ever send a HEAD request? If so, in what context?

Comment: Chrome issues HEAD requests to check DNS server behaviour http://serverfault.com/questions/235307/unusual-head-requests-to-nonsense-urls-from-chrome

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A browser will send a `HEAD` request if that is explicitly requested in an `XMLHttpRequest`, but I'm fairly certain that the browser will never send a `HEAD` request of its own accord. My evidence is that the Tornado web server defaults to [returning an error for `HEAD` requests](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/1ecc7386da17df3f1dfd100845355f7211119a62/tornado/web.py#L211) and I've never heard of anyone running into problems related to this (or even being aware of it).

`HEAD` is mostly obsolete IMHO: on a dynamic web site it is unlikely to be significantly more efficient than a `GET`, and it can usually be replaced by one of the following:

- Conditional `GET` with `If-Modified-Since` or `If-None-Match` (used for caching)
- Partial `GET` with `Range` header (used for e.g. streaming video)
- `OPTIONS` (used for CORS preflight requests)

Comment: Thanks. The scenario where I could imagine it being useful, would be before a download (right click save as). First issue a HEAD request, if there is a content-length header, make sure there is enough disk space to store the download before actually wasting bandwidth if there isn't room.